# Arrow keys don't work in irb/ruby command line scripts?

Tags: ruby, scripting

While using `gets` to accept user input, pressing the arrow keys outputs text to the screen, presumably the character codes. How can I prevent this from happening, and further how can I get the arrow keys to properly move the cursor around?

```
irb(main):001:0> foo = gets
^[[A^[[D^[[B^[[C    
=> "\e[A\e[D\e[B\e[C\n"
```

Edit: maybe I should mention I'm using Mac OS X and Terminal.app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Using Ruby's Readline Library](http://adam.blog.heroku.com/past/2008/1/22/using_rubys_readline_library/):

```
require 'readline'
foo = Readline::readline
```